# Getting the Registration ID from PHP which we sent from Android app

Tags: php, android, push-notification, android-c2dm

This is an effort to develop a Android application which enable C2DM

**Things I have done correctly**

- Get a valid Gmail address with C2DM
- Write an Android app for getting a registrationId from C2DM
- Get that registrationId from C2DM
- Pass that registrationId to the third party server (I sent to a php
  page) (*1*)
- Send it correctly (I checked it with the HttpEntity class in the same
  android app and I got the content of that page)
- Getting Google authentication ID in server side (used PHP)
- Open a Gmail account in my emulator (Menu - Settings - Accounts & sync - Add acount)

**Things I am confused**

- How that web page (*1*) get notified when my Android app passed a "http" request?
- How can I display the registrationId in the web page which sent by my Android app?

**Things that wont work**

- Sending PushNotification to the emulator which runs my Android app. Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121508/c2dm-implementation-php-code). That code is really good and first part also woks for me. But when I run the sendMessageToPhone() function it sends me 401. In my code I hard coded the values for;
- $authCode = Google authentication code I get
- $deviceRegistrationId = Code sent by the C2DM to my Android app

So please help me to clear my confusions and to correct my "wont work" activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplest code for sending POST request to PHP:

```
String url = "http://your.domain.com/path/to/your/post/request/handler.php";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
  List<NameValuePair> post = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationId", "[YOUR ID VALUE HERE]"));

  client.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(post));
  client.execute(new HttpPost(url));
} catch(IOException e) {
  //do something here
}
```

On server side(i.e. in your PHP script) you can use $_POST superglobal variable which is populated from POST data and it's a simple associative array. Something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['registrationId'])) {
  //do something here
}
```

Comment: hi... @ioseb thanks for the reply. Can you please send me the "handler.php" code? I have done the Java coding for the Android. But need the PHP script for handle the request sent by the C2DM after I run my Android app. Just the handler.php I wrote PHP script for get Google Authentication ID and send push notification to mobile. Thanks in advance.