# Google C2DM quick questions

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am implementing C2DM push into an Android-app, and have come to the part where i need to actually send the message to Googles servers. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121508/c2dm-implementation-php-code on the topic, but have a few quick questions.

In the googleAuthenticate argument "source", should the AppName be the appname from the AndroidManifest? Is the version the versionname or versioncode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source attribute not to be necessary. Just omit it and the ClientLogin works fine. I also have no version parameter in the ClientLogin call.

I use only: Email, Passwd, accountType=GOOGLE and service=ac2dm

Since the email is bound to the package name of your app and you need the registration_id to address a message thats all whats necessary.