# How does data synchronization work and how do I use it in server-client applications?

Tags: php, android, web-services, synchronization, client-server

I will demonstrate the problem on a real example so the situation:

1. there is a website (eg: real example:
   http://www.news.com.au/breaking-news)
2. From the website I want to parse data "last breaking news". This
   should be a service (based on php, c # aspx ...) do that is by our
   side written off. The data are parsed and prepared in XML or
   similar.
3. There are a number of clients (desktop variant, mobile ...), when
   the news with a new PUSH (like an exchange server does that) should
   be notified.

I do not know exactly how to do the connection / synchronization between 2) and 3).

One idea would be sent by a client in an interval and then requests for the service needs to make a PUSH.
Or is there some other variant to solve this? Maybe so that the client is waiting and the only large part of the service intervals made ​​without the requests?

Are there any specific approaches, ideas, proposals?

Thanks in advance,
best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The client (i.e. Android app) is quering the server periodically, sending a timestamp value. The server compares the timestamp with its data and replies only with relevant (newest) data.
2. Push notifications: on Android you can use C2DM. How to do it in PHP? See:
   [C2DM implementation PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121508/c2dm-implementation-php-code/5232809#5232809)