# Warning on GCM with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging, yii2

I'm using  GCM in php. Everything is fine. But im getting response as

```
"Field \"data\" must be a JSON array: example\n"
```

My code for GCM is

```
function sendNotification($registrationIdsArray, $messageData) {
        $data = array(
            'data' => $messageData,
            'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
        );
        var_dump($data);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
```

and my $data object is

```
{"data":"example","registration_ids":["apikey1", "apikey2"]}
```

What is the missing code for GCM here.

Comment: $messageData shoul be an array not string

Comment: How can i change into array?

Comment: I changed $messageData into array . but now im getting "{\"multicast_id\":8115817839537145784,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"error\":\"MismatchSenderId\"}]}"

Comment: check this link for this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313342/why-do-i-get-mismatchsenderid-from-gcm-server-side

Comment: I have solved this error. but im getting null notification. my $data object is {"data":{"title":"testing","text":"example","time":""},"registration_ids":["apikey1"]}

Comment: where you are getting null in response or in android side

Comment: Yes. null in notification on mobile

Comment: can you provide the code of android part

Comment: I passed data.message. Its working. I need to send more objects with data. How can i know the list of objects for data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data which you are passing should be an array not a string like this

```
  $messageData =  array(
    'success' => 1,
    'title' => $data['title'],
    'desc' => $data['message']
  );
```