# Parse push not sending notification to some devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

When I am sending notification from **Parse Push** it send notification to some devices and  for the rest it shows GCM- Mismatch sender id. I have configured Parse configuration properly in my app but sometime It store my app generated GCM ID in it's device token field and then giving this **GCM- Mismatch sender ID** error. How to resolve this error?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: I am sending message from both  rest client and parse dashboard.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313342/why-do-i-get-mismatchsenderid-from-gcm-server-side

Comment: I have properly configured  my app and sending message properly from my web server by my android sender id, but I want to send notification from parse.com.  Parse.com storing my sender id generated registration id in its device token field of its Installation table, So it is giving this error.

Comment: What Android Parse SDK version are you using?

Comment: Previously I am using 1.8.2 and yesterday I update it to 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

**Likely** your app uses **more than one** push provider including Parse. Fortunately Parse has provided a good meta-data. As Parse said in it's [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-setting-up-push) you should provide each **Sender_ID** that your app uses to push messages, if you use another push provider in addition to Parse. Take a look at below:

> The Parse Android SDK chooses a reasonable default configuration so
>   that you do not have to worry about GCM registration ids, sender ids,
>   or API keys. In particular, the SDK will automatically register your
>   app for push at startup time using Parse's sender ID
>   (**1076345567071**) and will store the resulting registration ID in
>   the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation.
>
> However, as an advanced feature for developers that want to send
>   pushes from multiple push providers, Parse allows you to optionally
>   register your app for pushes with additional GCM sender IDs. To do
>   this, specify the additional GCM sender ID with the following
>   `<meta-data>` tag as a child of the `<application>` element in your app's
>   AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
>            android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID" />;
> ```
>
> In the sample snippet above, YOUR_SENDER_ID should be replaced by a
>   numeric GCM sender ID. Note that the Parse SDK expects you to prefix
>   your sender ID with an id: prefix, as shown in the sample snippet.
>
> If you want to register your app with multiple additional sender IDs,
>   then the android:value in the `<meta-data>` element above should hold a
>   comma-delimited list of sender IDs, as in the following snippet:
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
>            android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID_1,YOUR_SENDER_ID_2,YOUR_SENDER_ID_3"/>;
> ```

Comment: Yes I am previously using my own GCM push notification with parse push and I have also configured this metadata in manifest file.  But when I am sending notification from parse dashboard I got this error.

Comment: Are you test against your user base or only on your own device?

Comment: I am testing against my user base.

Comment: Since this issue is app related, so you should keep this tip in a corner of your mind that, you wouldn't see this error when all of your users update their apps to the resolved version.

Comment: I am inserting  records in Installation table from very long time, So it should send the notification to all devices. What  is the exact reason for this error.