# MismatchSenderId when Sending Push

Tags: android, push

```
{
multicast_id: 6483271358081384000,
success: 0,
failure: 1,
canonical_ids: 0,
results: [
{
error: "MismatchSenderId"
}
]
}
```

When I try to send Push to my device i got this Message.

And i checked my API key, sender id, they are absolutely fine
and i am able to create device token with sender id.
All are look good but don't know why this happen.

Answer:
Uninstall app and reinstall fresh app work for me.
because what iam doing is storing the device_id in PrefUtils

Comment: Have you seen this? It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313342/why-do-i-get-mismatchsenderid-from-gcm-server-side

Comment: yes i seen, i search a lot, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below script in your terminal

```
curl -X POST \  
-H "Authorization: key= write here api_key" \  
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \  
-d '{  
"registration_ids": [ "write here reg_id generated by gcm"], 
      "data": { "message": "Manual push notification from Rajkumar" },"priority": "high"
}' \  
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

`MismatchSenderId` because within the same device you have logged with different keys. to solve this problem uninstall an app and run it again and update the registration key. and then run the CURL script in your terminal which I post above it will give success message and you will get a notification to your device