# Push Notifications to Ionic app using GCM

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm writing an Ionic app and trying to make Push Notifications to work.

I'm using the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin to do so.

On the "$ionicPlatform.ready" event I get the device token

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
  android: {
    senderID: "36112019308"
  }
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('tkn', data.registrationId );
});
```

well, here I get the registration id. Now, when I try to follow the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en), with a curl command like the following

```
curl --header "Authorization: key={KEY_GOT_ON_GOOGLE_CONSOLE}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"THE_REGISTRATION_ID_GOT_ON_DEVICE"]}"
```

I get the error:

```
{"multicast_id":4787366485826638756,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Well, I am confident that the key and the registration id are correct because if I change the key I get **unauthorized** error and if I change the registration id I get **InvalidRegistration** error

What could be that I am doing wrong?

**Aditional Info**

- Testing with debug build

Comment: Have you checked this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36492797/2549619 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The error message was really misleading.

The full token returned after registration was something like this:

```
dWWt-ohQFWg:APA91bFBgEU1aRyykLCw2lNat57WSePvbXyiLcCoHh6Tt6dkzXs5HUNl8C4wDL-BgaBrzJJc0lHH8IGQ3zACcfyQEdQmpKTJWOWshWKIH0e_RByg5zkhX0AlvFL4_0DLMzd_Hz1YKZ1g
```

For some reason I was only using what came after the ":" and in this case the error was **MismatchSenderId**. I was convinced that the registration was ok because if I changed anything on the string it returned **InvalidRegistration**. But in fact the whole string should be used, including the part before the ":"