# Using GCM for push notifications to both Android and iOS devices

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an iOS app which need to get push notifications(using GCM) from web service(Made of Python).

Currently the web service works fine with Android devices, but it reports **Error=MismatchSenderId**, when I check this error in the online doc, it suggests the sender_id and API_key are not matched.  The thing is, as I understand it(could be wrong), for iOS SDK, unlike the Android's, it doesn't need sender_id.

The tricky part is I have no access to the web service yet(which the collaboration party claim the Android app works fine with it).  Could anyone shred a light on what steps should I take to fix this issue?

THanks in advance.

Comment: I use a tool called "GcmServerDemo", it works fine.  Does this mean I need to change something in web service?

Comment: Check this SO question [11313342](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313342/why-do-i-get-mismatchsenderid-from-gcm-server-side) and [12949487](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949487/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-and-missmatched-sender-id?lq=1) if it can help you :)