# PHP GCM error message MismatchSenderId

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing the problem with GCM push notification. I am getting the following error.

```
{
  "multicast_id":4630467710672911593,
  "success":0,
  "failure":1,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[{
      "error":"MismatchSenderId"
  }]
}
```

Following is the code. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
public function gcmPush() 
{
    $regId = "APA91bHFcgOssQZEqtdUk3EC1ojwC5-LVG3NPV2bMqKyC9rPymR6StmAbz-N7Ss8fnvruZhWWNrR3lmBqpjQItlu00AKHPbltBclUJF-EfC5qG4CF2xiuYYC0NCf8u5rbiYFk8ARhIT4lY2AEPWzGpl1OtTvQEC0gA"; 
    $registatoin_ids = array($regId); 
    $message = array("msg" => 12345); 

    $this->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
}

public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) 
{
  // Set POST variables
  $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';         
  define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyBavsIgQKo1Nf9wKZ5o_fGvE_6MI52LFR0');
  $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
  );
  $headers = array(
   'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
   'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

  // Open connection
  $ch = curl_init();

  // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

  // Execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch)
  if ($result === FALSE) {
      die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }

  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When sending messages using GCM , I keep getting response : MismatchSenderId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307689/when-sending-messages-using-gcm-i-keep-getting-response-mismatchsenderid)

Comment: Hi please check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307689/when-sending-messages-using-gcm-i-keep-getting-the-response-mismatchsenderid     I hope useful for you.

Answer (score 9):

**"MismatchSenderId"** is the obvious problem that we are getting nowadays.

Here are the possible cases that cause this problem.

**Case 1: Mismatching Sender ID ->**
Please check the Project number which you are using. If it's is correct or not.

**Case 2: Wrong API Key ->**
Please be sure that you are using the same API_Key or not. And in most of the cases, we need to generate Server_Key instead of Android_Key.

**Case 3: Wrong Device's ID ->**
Most of the time the problem is due to the wrong Device ID(Registration ID generated by GCM).

*Please be ensure that that Whenever you generate new API key, the device id's of your device gets changed. Then it will take almost 5 five minutes to get an effect.*

**Note :** Your device id is bound with the API KEY.

So....

> --New Key created.
>
> --GCM for Android Turned "on" in Google Dev. Console.
>
> --Device registered with backend fine (Android Project is doing its job). Device key on the server.
>
> --Send to device. Fail! The same message is returned from GCM everytime.
>
> To Recap. This is NOT an Android Studio, Android OS, or Device issue.
> The GCM servers are not even trying to send the message to the device.
> My server sends to GCM, it returns the message...
>
> ```
> {"multicast_id":6047824495557336291,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
> ```
>
> to the server. As far as I can tell this means the Device's ID (the
> one returned to the device when it registered for a push, and the one
> saved on the backend (in the control panel) does not match, or is
> somehow not associated with the API Key used when sending the message.
>
> Sending, of course, starts on my server, goes to GCM, then goes to the
> device.
>
> This is what's not happening. The message goes from my server to GCM
> and back to my server - with the error.
>
> Super frustrating as all of you can imagine - we've all been through
> this nightmarish stuff before :-)

Source : https://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=C3CED924C86828C2172E924