# android push notification MismatchSenderId error

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send push notification to android device, but every time i am getting the error following error

```
{
    "multicast_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also uninstall/install application many times on my device but it doesnt works for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

double check the Sender ID and API_KEY, they must match or else you will get that MismatchSenderId error. In the Google API Console, look at the URL of your project:

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:xxxxxxxxxxx
```

The xxxxxxxxx is the project ID, which is the sender ID.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered correctly? Do your sender-id and API_KEY match?

Check out the solutions here as your question is a possible duplicate:

[Why do I get "MismatchSenderId" from GCM server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313342/why-do-i-get-mismatchsenderid-from-gcm-server-side)

[When sending messages using GCM, I keep getting the response 'MismatchSenderId'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307689/when-sending-messages-using-gcm-i-keep-getting-response-mismatchsenderid)