# Not getting push notification from GCM after sending few notifications

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want push notification by using GCM, all things are done properly, like API key & others.

I got success & also received notification, but after sending few notifications now i'm not getting any notification & getting following erro

`{"multicast_id":7413445345804388431,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}`

please help for this, Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

`error":"MismatchSenderId` it says that your sending push notifications from another sender id, not from your registered send id. please check your sender id properly.

Double check the `Sender ID` and `APK_KEY`, they must match or else you will get that MismatchSenderId error. In the Google API Console, look at the URL of your project:

Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316399/964741

Comment: what i'm saying is initially i was getting notification, i didnt even change 1 letter from code otherwise i m not getting it now....rmbr no change in code

Comment: OK. may be you did't change in code. Please check all the values properly first. because if you did't change  you could't get any error instead of getting notifications..so please verify those values properly.

Comment: is there any chances that google block notifications after sending notifications at a time??