# APNs certificate connection with GCM for different types of app

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing app for app store and enterprise. For that, I'm using GCM service for push notification. While testing I'm getting all notifications but the time I create build with enterprise, I'm not getting single message. In backend it's showing 'NotRegistered' or 'MisMatchSenderId'. What am I doing wrong?

some doubts:

1.For development using p12(development APNs) and sandboxing = YES.

2.For AppStore production using p12(production APNs) and sandboxing = NO.

3.For Enterprise using p12(development APNs) and sandboxing = YES.

Please any one clarify for enterprise and Ad hoc I should use p12(development APNs) or p12(production APNs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please any one clarify for enterprise and Ad hoc I should use p12(development APNs) or p12(production APNs)?**

You need to use production APNS certificate in Enterprise and Adhoc. You can only use the development APNS certificate in Development Stage.

**In backend it's showing 'NotRegistered' or 'MisMatchSenderId'. What am I doing wrong?**

You got an error "MisMatchSenderId" because GCM responds that the device push token is invalid. Possible cause is device is marked as inactive in the backend. A device will be marked as "active: false" when its token is returned as invalid after sending a push notification to it.

You can refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307689/when-sending-messages-using-gcm-i-keep-getting-the-response-mismatchsenderid).