# How to implement GCM in Google AppEngine?

Tags: java, android, servlets, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a PHP Developer and Web Designer. In my work a partner asked me if I could set up a Google Cloud Messaging server.

I read the documentation but couldn't find a clear tutorial to set up this server.

I got no knowleadge about Java so it makes my job harder. I could "compile" a war file using ant as [GCM Demo Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) says. But I can't deploy it to my AppEngine server to try it out (It's my first time using AppEngine too).

Could you give me some steps to create my own GCM server?

Sorry about my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: How can't you deploy to App Engine? What specific problem or error are you encountering?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I have the gcm-demo.war compiled in /dist directory inside the gcm-server-demo directory. But I don't know how to deploy it or how to insert it in a Eclipse project.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging  i have used it and working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you very much user1462827! I have one question, how can I get the registration id? Is something that has to be done by the android app? I need that id to test the script, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A easy way to import the gcm-server-demo to eclipse:

①Download a “Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers”，and create a dynimic web project.

②Copy the ‘src’ and ‘webcontent’  from the gcm-server-demo to cover the web project.

③Add a server like tomcat or jetty to run the project.

And the registration id is sent by the Android application with a 'Post' request.
You can handle it with servlet or PHP