# how to do Push Notification using GCM in android

Tags: android, android-intent, client, google-cloud-messaging, user-registration

Currently C2DM has moved to GCM, and i am in an starting stage in using GCM,  can any one guide me what are the process to use GCM in android, how to register the device.

thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: i have answered similar question before, take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464184/google-cloud-messaging/12437549#12437549

Comment: Also have a look on: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494842/when-register-for-push/12494979#12494979][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494842/when-register-for-push/12494979#12494979

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post. It shows the end to end process of registering your app with Google, setting up the client code, and sending notifications via GCM to your Android device.

http://fryerblog.com/post/30057483199/implementing-push-notifications-with-gcm