# Android 4.1.2 cloud messaging

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I've installed the new version of android 4.1.2 on my nexus 7. Now all my apps using the old c2dm system not getting any notifications at all.

Is there a need to change to the new gcm system to support cloud messaging on android 4.1.2 devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **YES**.

> Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
>   This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota
>   requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using
>   C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to
>   migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for
>   Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more
>   information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

[see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464184/google-cloud-messaging/12437549#12437549) how to integrate to GCM.

Comment: "However, apps using C2DM will continue to work." - It seems not right in Andorid 4.1.2