# Sending notifications to Google Cloud Messaging with php gives me Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: php, android, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Searching for some info about how to send notifications using GCM but with PHP instead of servlets, i found this: [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

I tested the working code of the responses of these questions, also i created a Key for browser apps (with referers), and i give permissions to this ip: *.mywebsite.com/* (te php file is on this url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/~jma/cHtml5/cap/kk.php")

But i'm getting this response: **Unauthorized Error 401**

What i'm doing wrong?

this is the php file:

```
<?php
    // Replace with real server API key from Google APIs        
    $apiKey = "fictional key";

    // Replace with real client registration IDs
    $registrationIDs = array( "APA91asdasdSDGGS232S13S4213abGqiNhCIXKjlxrkUYe_xTgTacNGB5n16b380XDd8i_9HpKGRHkvm8DDet4_WK3zumjDEKkTRWLgPS7kO-BrKzWz7eWFQaDD9PJ8zA6hlSqL9_zH21P8K22ktGKmo_VIF6YAdU9ejJovrKBTpgQktYkBZBf9Zw","APAasdasd32423dADFG91bHYYxYB7bFiX5ltbJt6A-4MBiNg7l4RS4Bqf3jIfYviaaUfZ810XJo2o66DY9-jdeJk_JR8FIZCyrmCv-eu_WLkGZ8KaoHgEDR_16H2QPm98uHpe1MjKVXbzYc4J89WMmcIrl5tHhWQnIQNzaI6Zp6yyFUNUQ");

    // Message to be sent
    $message = "Test Notificación PHP";

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    //print_r($result);
    //var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: if that's your real registration ID, I'd suggest you generate a new one. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved!!!

you must use Key for server apps (with IP locking) instead of browser key

:)

Comment: @Fewtron The concept of _Server_ and _Browser_ specific keys allows for you to monitor where your traffic is going and to allow specific keys to be used in specific locations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the key for server apps in the field of API key in your server side coding.
While creating the server key don't enter anything inside IP address field.