# Getting error in Android GCM Notification

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with GCM Notification in my Android Project.
But I am getting error when I integrate with server Like

Unauthorized
Error 401

When I run same code on localhost everything works fine without any error.& I am getting notification also in my android emulator from localhost.

please help.

Comment: put your send massage code.. and you server url..

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ I have followed this link.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285123/sending-notifications-to-google-cloud-messaging-with-php-gives-me-unauthorized-e)

Comment: I have already set server key though I am getting this error..

Comment: You're likely to get a better, more helpful and tailored response if you post code samples so that people can see what you're doing. What you have here is the equivalent of asking a doctor friend to help you feel better and telling them that when you move your arm, you feel pain.