# Issues+Clarification: Sending message from Raspberry Pi to Android Phone using Google cloud Messaging

Tags: android, python, raspberry-pi, urllib2, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Raspberry Pi and Google Cloud Messaging. What I want to do is as follows: Raspberry Pi is reading some sensor data and I want to send the data to my Android Phone in real time, i.e. as soon as a sensor reading is received it will be pushed to the phone. I looked into various ways to do this, and think using Google Cloud Messaging will be most suitable for me. So, I did the following:

1. Created a GCM project online
2. In the project, I generated a server API key with the Raspberry Pi's IP address.
3. Then ran the following program from RPi. The API in the code is the above API (taken from [Google Cloud Messaging HTTP Error 400: Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697096/google-cloud-messaging-http-error-400-bad-request))

   import json

   ```
   import urllib

   import urllib2

       class RemoteAlert:
           def sendGCM(self, regid, email, entry_id, date_modified, kind):
               url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
               apiKey = MY_API
               myKey = "key=" + apiKey

               json_data = { "registration_id": regid, "data" : {
                   "entry_id" : entry_id,
                   "email": email,
                   "date_modified": date_modified,
                   "kind": kind,
                   "reg_id": regid,
                   },
               }
               headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': myKey}
               data = urllib.urlencode(json_data)               
               req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
               req.add_header("Authorization", myKey)               
               f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
               response = f.read()
               f.close()
               print "DONE"

       obj = RemoteAlert()
       print obj.sendGCM("1234", "xxxxxx@gmail.com", "24", "10-09-2014", "VAL")
   ```

My issues and questions:

1. When I am running the above code from RPi I am getting 'Authorization Error 401'. Why?
2. Have I completed all the steps properly? Can I simply run the above code from my RPi without installing any GCM server anywhere?
3. I don't know what kind of code I need to write in the GCM project site to receive/send/use this message.
4. After this part works, I will write a client program to receive the RPi data in my android phone.

I have already checked the following pages for help:

1. [Sending notifications to Google Cloud Messaging with php gives me Unauthorized Error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285123/sending-notifications-to-google-cloud-messaging-with-php-gives-me-unauthorized-e)
2. http://fryerblog.com/post/30057483199/implementing-push-notifications-with-gcm

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: HI Kajarid.. I am also working on the same.. did you found any solution of below issue. if yes please update it in answer filed.. It will really help to me..

Comment: HI Kajarid.. I am also working on the same.. did you found any solution of below issue. if yes please update it in answer filed.. It will really help to me..Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dhrumil, please see the Answer I posted just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the above error. But I could successfully send push notification to Android phone using Amazon SNS with GCM!

From my IoT device I sent sensor data to my web service hosted on Amazon EC2. From EC2 I pushed the data to Android phone using SNS and GCM. It worked without any trouble.

I used web services to send data to EC2 instance. But Amazon Kinesis is a more efficient way to stream data to Amazon cloud in real time.

AWS gives free membership to try out many of their cloud utilities. Kinesis is not free, hence I didn't try it out. But I know people using it.

You can download entire Android project source code from Amazon SNS official tutorial site and use it after a little bit of personalization.