# GCM with WordPress blog - Android

Tags: android, wordpress, blogs, google-cloud-messaging

all materials I have studied about GCM seem to talk about java web server, which is not my case.
How would I implement Google Cloud Messaging with WordPress powered blog? Is there a plugin possibly?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement GCM with PHP very easily.

I followed the answer located at the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253231/864538

It's pretty straight forward and should be helpful. You could incorporate that into a plugin if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

On the WordPress repository is a plugin called wp gcm. Its a really great one try it out!

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gcm