# Multiple device push notifications to Android from PHP

Tags: php, android, notifications, push

How can I send push notification to multiple Android devices from [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

I have working code for sending it to a single device, but not for multiple devices.

Comment: you need to go thru GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Its very vast so please can any body provide me direct link for the example?

Comment: @AnshitaPatel It is the very first [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11253231/181714) in the question link I provided. It even has a code example that you could adapt to your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

As per Google’s documentation,

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that helps developers send data from servers to their Android applications on Android devices

Using this service you can send data to your application whenever new data is available instead of making requests to server in timely fashion.

- Have a look at [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). It is good guiding tutorial for GCM notifications
- Also there is a good working example of [How to implement GCM PHP Push Server for Android](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/07/gcm-php-push-server.html)