# Not able to send messages via GCM

Tags: php, android, ajax, google-cloud-messaging

I am using a PHP script to push messages onto android devices via GCM. I have an html form that takes in a text input as the message and then pushes this message to the android device.

Now when i tried it with two separate fields 1. Excerpt 2. Message
My android device receives a null message.

I need to know where am I going wrong.

This is my HTML Form

```
                    <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')"> 
                        <label>User:</label> <span><?php echo $row["id"] ?></span> 
                        <div class="clear"></div> 
                        <div class="send_container"> 
                            <textarea rows="3" name="excerpt" cols="10" class="txt_excerpt" placeholder="Type excerpt here"></textarea>
                            <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/> 
                            <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/> 
                        </div> 
                    </form>
```

This is the ajax Script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    }); 
    function sendPushNotification(id){ 
        var data = $('form#'+id).serialize(); 
        $('form#'+id).unbind('submit'); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "send_message.php", 
            type: 'GET', 
            data: data, 
            beforeSend: function() { 

            }, 
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) { 
                  $('.txt_message').val("");
                  $('.txt_excerpt').val("");    
            }, 
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

            } 
        }); 
        return false; 
    } 
</script>
```

This is the Send_message.php code

```
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"]) && isset($_GET["excerpt"])) { 
    $regId = $_GET["regId"]; 
    $message = $_GET["message"];
    $excerpt = $_GET["excerpt"];

    include_once './GCM.php'; 

    $gcm = new GCM(); 

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId); 
    $message = array("news" => $message, "exc" => $excerpt); 


    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message); 

    echo $result;
```

This is the GCM.php Code

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message, $excerpt) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,

        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

This is the android GCMIntentService Code

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message"); 
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("news");
    String excerpt = intent.getExtras().getString("exc");
    Log.i("Received ->", excerpt+" "+message);
    if(message!=null)
    {
        displayMessage(context, message); 
    // notifies user 
        generateNotification(context, message); 
    }
}
```

All I see on my device is a blank notification whenever I push a message from the server.

Comment: Please check below link for GCM PHP with android which working fine for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18911631/1614340

Comment: I don't know PHP, but there seems to be a mismatch in the number of parameters between the function declaration `public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message, $excerpt)` and call `$gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11253231/2106820