# running a php code from a link without redirection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to execute a php code when a user click on a given link , i've tried the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doSomething() {
 $.get("up.php");
 return false;
 }
</script>


  </head>

  <body>

  <center>
  <a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Click Me!</a>


   </center>

   </body>
  </html>
```

where up.php is a php code that implement android GCM mechanism similer to the one in the link : [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

but unfortunately when the link is clicked nothing happens , the php code not executed ,and only the url of the page change form *****.com/test.html to *****.com/test.html# , and by the way I've tested the php code and its works fine  so it is not a problem in php code , so what i have missed here? why the code is not executed?

Comment: I've tried all the solutions below but non of them works for me , any idea?

Comment: are you sure, that up.php does not get executed? try writing something in a logfile when executing up.php. The way you wrote it, up.php may be executed, but you don't do anything with the result of up.php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution , the problem that the jquery library is not included probably in my code

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you may need to call some JavaScript from within a link. Normally, when user click on a link, the browser loads a new page (or refreshes the same page).

This might not always be desirable. For example, you might only want to dynamically update a form field when the user clicks a link.

To prevent the load from refreshing, you could use the JavaScript void() function and pass a parameter of 0 (zero) as below.

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="return doSomething(); " />Click Me!</a>
```

Now if you want to use href="#", make sure onclick always contains `return false;` at the end.

**OR**

Use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery. $.get() will be something like below.

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
 $('.result').html(data);
 alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

for further help check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

```
function doSomething() {
$('#result').load('up.php', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**When you are using `Jquery` should be :**

```
function doSomething(){
    $.get('up.php', function(data) {
        $('.data').html(data);
    });
}
```

**Link**

To stop page refreshing, you can use the javascript void() function and pass parameter of 0.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return doSomething();">Click Me!</a>`

```
<div class="data"></div>
```

**This div is used to display up.php result.**

Answer (score 0):

Ok start of by using fire bug and watch the console and network panels
Ensure the browser is trying to get something and not returning a 404 or a php error on the get

Look into prevent default http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
To stop the original link functionality working

If you still want them to move to the link use a window location or...

Look into bootstrap link buttons

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons
( the link button )