# GCM demo server - specify message

Tags: android, tomcat, google-cloud-messaging

I'm running the GCM demo server and it works quite well, but there's just one last problem I have: What do I have to do to send a message with content, there's no field for that in the demo server. Or does anyone have another server which I can run on an Apache Tomcat server?

Please help!

Comment: As you can run php scripts on apache tomcat server > look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Isnt there any possibility to run it without php and mysql?

Answer (score 1):

In the GCMUtils project I have created a test server where you very easily can send messages. It is a simple maven plugin, here is more information: https://code.google.com/p/gcmutils/wiki/MavenPlugin#Test_server

It does not run on tomcat (it uses jetty), but maybe it can be useful if you want to test your gcm client implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In GCM demo server sample, if you open SendAllMessageServlet.java, you can add your content by modifying line 81.

`Message message = new Message.Builder().build();`

to

`Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("subject", "Hello World").build();`

Then, the client can get your content in onMessage() method using intent.getStringExtra("subject");