# gcm message through javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send gcm message through javascript code. For this, we need to post a json object.

url and json object format is given in gcm docs: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html.

For testing purpose I had written a java code which works perfectly. But the javascript code doesn't work. If anyone has some sample working code(javascript for gcm), please post.

```
String body = "registration_id=proper_id&data.number=12345678";
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(url);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + key);
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
```

javascript code :

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =    http.responseText;
}
}
http.open("POST", url, false);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "key=proper_api_key");
var data = '{ "collapse_key": "qcall","time_to_live": 108, "delay_while_idle": true,"data": {"number":"12345678"},"registration_ids":["proper_id"]}';
http.send(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work due to [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

> In computing, the same-origin policy is an important security concept
>   for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as
>   JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port
>   number – to access each other's methods and properties with no
>   specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.

In short: You can't send HTTP Post to other Domains than the one from where your script executes.

Here you can see the [rules of the Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules)

You would need to user your Java Code or if your Hoster does not support Java you could use PHP. [This question about GCM and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging) seem to have a working PHP Script for GCM.

Good Luck