# GCM not allowing to send notification

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on sending push notification to GCM server. I followed php tutorial for that. But once I execute it, it is showing curl error saying that `"Failed to connect to 74.125.142.95: Permission denied'"`. I tried every api key I generated for my server, but still giving the same problem. Can anyone please explain me why I'm getting this error and a solution for it. I'm in a real need of it. Thanks.

Comment: Check your network proxy... same is blocking the ip.

Comment: Chek this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546684/access-denied-from-curl-on-remoter-server

Comment: @HarishGodara: I checked that question before posting. Didn't work.

Comment: @PankajKumar: Please tell how to do that one. I don't know about it.

Comment: contact your network admin