# Advantage of using Java EE over PHP for Android GCM

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

My Android app needs both downstream and upstream from and to the server. So I decide to use GCM XMPP in my web server. But does XMPP support php web server? If it supports, is there any advantage of using J2EE web server over PHP web server? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the platform you're more familiar with. The Web bits are but support infrastructure for the Android app. Also, when cosidering cheap web hosting, PHP is more likely to be supported than Java.

Comment: Thx Seva, I thought android uses Java and J2EE would be a better choice(at lease both using Java), but I actually already implemented web server using php, so can you suggest me some gcm xmpp example using php as web server?

Comment: Don't have one on hand, look it up. Google is as open to you as it is for me.

Comment: Thx Seva, I found one, if anyone like me is searching for a tutorial using php as gcm server, pls refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the platform you're more familiar with. The Web bits are but support infrastructure for the Android app. Also, when cosidering cheap web hosting, PHP is more likely to be supported than Java.