# GCM upstream data from device to 3rd party Server via php

Tags: php, android, python, google-cloud-messaging

I found links [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging) or http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/, both explain how to downstream data from 3rd party server to device(s) using cURL. But can anyone give me one example of how to upstream data from device to 3rd party server via php. Android provides us with both java and python(XMPP).

Answer (score 0):

Cause my main task is to sync local db with remote db, so using SyncAdapter http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
is a better choice over GCM