# notify user when website has changed using c2dm in android

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

i want to make app that make a notification when breaking news has arrived to news website
during my search i found two ways to do that 
1- using c2dm server & php & database 
2- using timer that scan the website automaticly every  time period i decide it

can any one help me by give me an example code for each method or a Tutorial for each method

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on GCM as well. The first comment already told you the right way to solve your problem, but I wanna add something more is that [This excellent tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Read it, try to understand it. I think it is quite clear. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

C2DM is deprecated. You could use GCM instead. Go through [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) how to get started with it.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging) too.

Comment: whats method to add website that i want to subscribe

Comment: You need to create a project on Google Apis. It gives an Api Key when you add ip of your website. And it gives project id, using which the android app registers to the GCM server.

Comment: So every time you want to push a message, ask GCM server to send it to device supplying the device token.