# GCM registering but not receiving messages on pre 4.0.4. devices

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Please help me out if you can. I've been trying to implement a basic gcm setup. On the server side I'm using php code from the top answer over here - [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)
And on the client side I've followed Google's GCM tutorial.
The whole thing is working fine on my Nexus 4, but it won't work on the two pre 4.0.4 devices i've tried.
One is htc one v running 4.0.3 and the other is sony ericsson running 2.3.4.
It could be something about the pre 4.0.4 devices thing, but they are registering successfully and giving me regids properly. They just won't receive any messages,though the gcm server is receiving them and sending back message ids with success.. even the broadcast receiver doesn't fire. If you have any idea why this is happening could you help me out please? Both devices have registered google accounts by the way.

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gole.firstgcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />




    <permission android:name="com.gole.firstgcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.gole.firstgcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gole.firstgcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.gole.firstgcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="com.gole.firstgcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the php implementation. It's using static regids right now.. i'm getting those by dumping them in the log from the app. It's working fine i think because i'm receiving messages properly on my nexus 4. This gives me three message ids when executed.

```
<?php

// Replace with real BROWSER API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "myapikey";

// Replace with real client registration IDs 
$registrationIDs = array(  "regid1", "regid2" , "regid3" );


// Message to be sent
$message = "Hello";

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';



$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                );

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
echo "here";
// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){ echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);}
echo $result;

?>
```

This is my mainactivity.

```
package com.gole.firstgcm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public final static String test = "testing";
    String SENDER_ID = "142141320638";
    static final String TAG = "firstgcm";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    String regid;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mDisplay);
        context = getApplicationContext();







        //check google play services apk on device

        Boolean isAPKPresent = checkPlayServices();

        if (isAPKPresent == true)
        {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {

                registerInBackground();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, regid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), regid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Have regid now.


        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private String getRegistrationId(Context context){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;



    }

    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "hello");
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

        // Your implementation here.
    }


    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }




}
```

This is the broadcast receiver. This never gets called in the two devices, because the log doesn't show anything.

```
package com.gole.firstgcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "firstgcm";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        Log.i(TAG, "received gcm message");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

This is the intent service.

```
package com.gole.firstgcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    static final String TAG = "firstgcm";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: your manifest package name is "com.gole.firstgcm". you are putting the same in broadcaseReceiver I am assuming. or you are using "my.package.name" ?

Comment: Put your php part as well as application code!

Comment: yeah sorry about that.. i changed that just for the sake of the question.. forgot to change it in some place.. ignore that sorry..it isn't working with the real package name.. i'll add the php and java code..

Comment: Any news? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `my.package.name` with `com.gole.firstgcm`

Comment: yeah sorry about that.. i changed that just for the sake of the question.. forgot to change it in some place.. ignore that sorry..it isn't working with the real package name..