# android GCM not receiving

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

download GCMDemo from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Registering with Google Cloud Messaging
[https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:243064666795:access](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:243064666795%3aaccess)

Change ip with my local system `static final String SERVER_URL = "http://142.168.1.213/gcm_server_php/register.php";`

Change sender id like `static final String SENDER_ID = "243064666795";`

Change Google key, username, password, dbname in config.php

After then start project on emulator it's successfully register on device on server it display one device on browser also but when i send notification from browser it will not receive on device. what's wrong ?

Comment: The AndroidHive demo you followed has actually been deprecated. Use this : http://techlovejump.in/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/

Comment: @Dhaval you had try it's working?

Comment: @PankajAndroid I always use this code and its work fine for me

Comment: @kushPHP which code? techlove or androidehive?

Comment: Techlove works. I have successfully done it.

Comment: @Dhaval what is table structure of it becuase they had not mention it on site

Comment: Table Structure? I didn't get it. Please elaborate

Comment: it's storing device id on server side on mysql so in mysql what is table structure?

Comment: @PankajAndroid both are the same code only difference is androidhive use the opps concept and techlove directly use the core code

Comment: I didn't use PHP part so can't help you out there. I can only say that you should use Play services to implement GCM.

Comment: @kushPHP Please take a hard look. TechLoveJump utilises Play services. AndroidHive doesn't

Comment: @Dhaval from java side i had done but it's issu from server side

Comment: @PankajAndroid Sorry bt I am Php developer. I just got the device-id from android developer and send them push notification. So i don't knw abt play services

Comment: http://distriqt.com/post/1273 MayBe this can help. You should search google. You'll find plenty results. Check also this : http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');
        define('GCMAPIKEY','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        define('GCMPUSHURL', 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');  




    $ori_msg=substr($message,0,200);
    $querydevices="selectdevice_token from device_info where device_type='A'";
    $devicesres = mysql_query($querydevices) or die(mysql_error());      
        $devicecount = mysql_num_rows($devicesres);
if($devicecount > 0)
{

    while($fetchdevices = mysql_fetch_array($devicesres))
    {
        if($fetchdevices['device_token']!="0")
        {
           if($fetchdevices['device_token']!="")
            {
               $registrationIDs[]=$fetchdevices['device_token'];
            }
        }
    }   


      $fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs, //(android device ids[array()])
                'data'              => array( "message" => $ori_msg )
                );
      $payload = json_encode($fields);

     // echo $payload;
      $headers = array(
     'Authorization: key='.GCMAPIKEY,
     'Content-Type: application/json'
        );  




    $ch = curl_init();

      // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, GCMPUSHURL);
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );

      // Execute post
      $result = curl_exec($ch); 

      curl_close($ch);

    }
```

**EDIT**
and this is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `device_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_token` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: where i need to change this?

Comment: you just put the `GCMAPIKEY` and `$message` with your notification message and `$registrationIDs` is array so please pass your **device_token**  not device-id

Comment: can you help me from server side?

Comment: yea why not i edit my code for your database structure

Comment: till i had not create table for this tchnolive demo i had created table for androidhive. can we use same table or i have to create another table?

Comment: @pankajAndroid Now i make it completely work-full. and still you hace any confusion then please take a lot of help from this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54011/discussion-between-kushphp-and-pankajandroid).