# Can a Google Cloud Messaging message be sent from browser/Javascript?

Tags: android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging, android-networking

Question says it all. All the examples I can find are for `server<-->android`. 
I'm looking for `Javascript-->android`

Answer (score 0):

Paid version, try PubNub  [(Push to Android Example)](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/)  or Pusher API tools.

For open source solution, you might try [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-GCM-Google-Cloud-Messaging-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp)

Note the real trick is obtaining the RegID from your device.  See the answers in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging) to understand better what is going on...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing a GCM proxy hosted on AppEngine.