# GCM not show content on device

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I try push notification to android device with PHP. When i insert a text into text field and send it to android device. It sent success but no content in message on device.Why? And how do i fix it?
This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include('config/dbconnect_log.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'my google api key');

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    echo json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;

}

$pushStatus = '';

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT googleid FROM ggevent";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

        $gcmRegIds = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $i++;
            $gcmRegIds[floor($i/1000)][] = $query_row['googleid'];
        }

    }
    $pushMessage = $_POST['message'];
    if(isset($gcmRegIds) && isset($pushMessage)) {

        $message = array('msg' => $pushMessage);
        $pushStatus = array();
        foreach($gcmRegIds as $val) $pushStatus[] = sendPushNotification($val, $message);

    }   

}
?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
  <article class="module width_full">
    <form method = 'POST' action = ''>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea rows = 2 name = "message"  placeholder = 'Messages to Transmit via GCM'></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="submit_link">
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Send Push Notification" class="alt_btn">
                </div>
            </footer>
    </form>
    </article>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did client receive a notification? Let's try var_dump `$pushStatus`, `$val`, `$message`

Comment: i think my code have proplem. But i don't know it wrong some where.

Answer (score 0):

First register the device to GCM and get the gcm key. Send the notification to that device manually using the GCM key. Curl request to do so is

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -XPOST -d '{"data":{"New message through curl"},"registration_ids":["APA91bGe-Ihcjil6YXgLNEtf1fZCvcrgcn35rTOsHPrK7mxoz70TP6jmniChLXmIbLd642CWGo0fem9XrECa2ukvAvNYfNY7HcJ0JcxTInBxNn5Pml9YQIU6qwRVQ4v8GIE4oZv4vjoc"]}'
```

If you get the notification using this then your device has been registered successfully

For more info and detailed working classed for test go through following link

[GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Use the key 'msg' to retrieve the message on mobile......$message = array('msg' => $pushMessage);