# PHP heroku cURL not working

Tags: php, heroku, google-cloud-messaging

I've hosted an app on Heroku that uses the PHP code to send cURL request for google cloud messaging service using answer in this stackoverflow post

[GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

However the following code gives me an 500 error in Heroku while it works perfectly well on my shared host, I'm new to Heroku so is there any specific thing I have to do to overcome the error?

```
<?php
    // Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
    $apiKey = "your api key";

    // Replace with the real client registration IDs
    $registrationIDs = array( "reg id1","reg id2");

    // Message to be sent
    $message = "hi Shailesh";

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
    //print_r($result);
    //var_dump($result);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide server error log? Maybe curl extension is not installed ?

Comment: That's what I thought but their documentation says that things like cURL is pre installed https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

Comment: It seems like server fault. So without error log It will be very difficult to resolve this

Comment: As a wild guess, could it be to do with SSL certificates being different, as you are calling a `https` URL?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I try to call a webservice using nusoap, it uses cURL, and is throwed the follow error:

HTTP Error: cURL ERROR: 27: SSL: couldn't create a context: error:140A90C4:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed
url: https://_xxxxx_:443/_xxxxx_.Services
content_type: 
http_code: 0
header_size: 0
request_size: 0
filetime: -1
ssl_verify_result: 1
redirect_count: 0
total_time: 0.241638
namelookup_time: 0.004367

Comment: In other server its running ok.